# are both topologies same

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Consider the space $(\mathbb{C^2},T)$ where $T$ is the product topology on $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ having Zarisky topology. Now let $T_2$ defines another topology on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with open sets $D_{I}=\{(a,b) \mid I \not\subset (x-a,y-b))$ (here $I$ runs over all ideals $I \in  \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ Then question is, is $T=T_2$ ?

My answer is no, consider $I=(x-y)$ so $D_{I}=\{(a,b) \mid a\neq b\}$. Now suppose $T=T_2$ then we should have to able to be write $D_I$ is union of elements of $T$. But open sets in $T$ are of from $A\times B$ where $A,B$ are complement of finite sets, so contains some $(x,x)$. So $D_I$ can't be union of elements of $T$

Comment: So, $x-a$ and $y-b$ are polynomials in $ℂ[x]$ and $ℂ[y]$, right? This took me two minutes to grok, you should state that more clearly.

Comment: ohh okay, I'm editing

Comment: Also, what is the relation between $I$ and $D_I$? I don’t see it. Do you mean $D_I = \{(a,b) ∈ ℂ^2;~I \not\subseteq (X-a,Y-b)\}$? And $D_I$ for an ideal $I ⊂ ℂ[X,Y]$

Comment: I don't know how to write that "not subset thing" and yes that the definition of $D_I$ what you mentiones and $I$ runs over all ideals of $C[x,y]$

Comment: Ad “not subset”: `\not\subset` (or `\not\subseteq`).

Comment: Your argument's correct. Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know whether I'm doing correct or not, someone told me both topos are same, thats why was confused